# How to use html tag <div> in string textview

Tags: android, html, string, textview

I have activity consist of long textview must separated as multiple paragraphs by divider , im using this code :

```
TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text); 
        tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.planet)));
```

to get the text from strings and using html tags om it as :

```
<string name="planet">
  <![CDATA[ 
    // my text written here//
   ]]> 
 </string>
```

im try to add separator or divider in between each paragraph by add html divider tag 
      but its not work , i tried this but not working :

```
 <div class="aligncenter" style="width:400px;height:0;border-top:4px outset 
        #008000;font-size:0;">-</div>
```

also tried this also not working :

```
<div align="aligncenter" style="width:400px;height:0;border-top:4px outset 
        #008000;font-size:0;""></div>
```

so please any advice to apply that divider using htlm  tag

thanks for any help and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Html.fromHtml()` does not handle all the `HTML` tags.
Only basic tags like `<i> <b> <br/>` etc are handled. 
For more complex `HTML` tags that include tags like `<span>` or `<div>` use a `WebView` or you if its just the line break that you want then try a `<br/>` or a `\n`.

[Source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/text/Html.java) - Html.fromHtml. Search for `handleStartTag` on the source page to see more.

Comment: it will be horizontal colored line between each paragraph

Comment: what i have is very long text consists of paragraphs ,each 20 text line make paragraph then i have to start another pragraph with different subject so i want to separate between pragraphs with colored horezontal line , also i dont want to do it in xml as lets say 40 textview referd each one to string , but if ican to do it as one textview with multiple lines deviding the pragraps , if you have any other idea to do it , i will be appreciated that , thanks

Comment: As I said, use a WebView for handling other HTML tags. Or you can start a new question and ask the SO community.